# Need help analyzing Windows Performance Recorder ETL file to figure out whats causing slow boot on my SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, performance

My computers boot time suddenly doubled and I'm trying to figure out why. Boot time before was 15-20 seconds but now its 50+ seconds. I ran Windows Performance Recorder and I need help analyzing the ETL file. I uploaded it as a [zip file to OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArgD2nQVJ96Kgn19uNwhp4OoQ3lD).

What I have tried:

- Boot time slow with a normal / clean / safe boot no difference between them
- All drivers up to date on my Asus VIII Hero motherboard and installed the latest bios
- Turned off fast startup in power options
- Installed all of the latest Windows 10 updates and upgraded to v1803
- Firmware up to date on my Samsung 960 Pro NVMe SSD and healthy according to CrystalDiskInfo. Benchmark with CrystalDiskMark were good
- Ran SFC/Scannow showed no issues

My system specs:

- Motherboard: Asus MAXIMUS VIII HERO
- Processor: i7-6700k
- Memory: G.SKILL TridentZ RGB 32GB DDR4 3600MHz
- Graphics Card: EVGA 1080 Ti FTW3
- SSD: Samsung 960 Pro NVMe M.2 1TB

Comment: If you disable cam_v3.exe and Windows Defender what happens then?  If you're not sure where cam_v3.exe is being launched from at startup, Autorun could be useful - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: I have tried disabling Cam and all other non-microsoft applications with a clean boot and the boot time is slow. I need someone to analyze my WPR ETL file to see what is causing the delay

Comment: Has anyone been able to analyze my ETL file yet?